# Irreducible representations

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, group-representations

I was studying group theory yesterday and i had this question. If i have an irreducible representation D that belongs in G and another irreducible representation F that belongs in G, is it right to say that the direct product $D {\otimes} F$ is also an irreducible representation and if yes why? I thought of angular momentum, i.e $$|j_1,m_1>{\otimes}|j_2,m_2>=|j_1,m_1>|j_1,m_1>$$ which is an irreducible representation.

Comment: No. It is typically reducible, cf. [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform if we assume that F is a 1-dimensional representation of G then is the direct product an irreducible representation of G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the tensor product of two irreducible representations is reducible.  The best example is the coupling of two spin-1/2 states, which give
$$
\frac{1}{2}\otimes \frac{1}{2}=0\oplus 1\, .
$$

If one of the representation is 1-dimensional, then the result will usually remain irreducible.  For instance, the alternating representation ${\cal A}$ of $S_n$, when tensored with an irrep $\{\lambda\}$ of $S_n$, will give the irrep 
conjugate to $\{\lambda\}$.  Clearly the trivial irrep tensored with any irrep will give this same irrep back and nothing else.